# using tables when table is not defined in the config

Tags: php, sql-update

This is my **config** file . i have defined all things which i will using in my pages

```
<?php 
define("CONFIG","true");
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "test");
define("TABLE_NAME", "test1");
define("pFix", "");
define("USERNAME", "admin");
define("PASSWORD", "123");
        ?>
```

There are 3 tables in my database ie test1 , measures and nish . I want to use measures and nish in my join query with test1 but i have not defined measures and nish in the config file .how will i check how manay tables are there in my database and if want to use 2 tables or 3 tables how will i select them

Comment: First you fix your HTML. You cannot have `<form>` tags where you're putting them. `<tr><form><td></td></form></tr>` is outright invalid.

Comment: i wil fix it but please please help me with that problem first

Comment: how can you possibly expect a form to work properly if you're not even building a valid html page first? It's like you're complaining about your house falling down because it was built on quicksand. "oh, I'll fix that later".

Comment: ok then tel my mistake i will fix that things first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your problem if you change your code from:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?= $e[$i][$colnams[$ii]]?>">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" name="id[]" value="<?= $e[$i][$colnams[$ii]]?>">
```

After this change, you will receive the values as an array.

Comment: thnx for rply bt i also need the column names , how will i post it by using form

Comment: I hope to understand you. But you can name the array entries with the columnnames: `<input type="text" name="id[$colnams[$ii]]" value="<?= $e[$i][$colnams[$ii]]?>">`